# Nested NavigationLinks with `isActive=true` are not displaying correctly

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation

I've begun learning SwiftUI, but have had some issues when building up my NavigationView - I'm not sure if this is a bug, or if I'm misunderstanding how nested navigation links should work!

This is my current code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ViewOne()
    }
  }
}

struct ViewOne: View {
  @State var isActiveOne: Bool = true

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("View One")
      
      NavigationLink(
        destination: ViewTwo(),
        isActive: $isActiveOne,
        label: { EmptyView() }
      )
      
      Button(
        action: { self.isActiveOne = true },
        label: { Text("Set isActiveOne=true") }
      )
    }
  }
}

struct ViewTwo: View {
  @State var isActiveTwo: Bool = true

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("View Two")
      
      NavigationLink(
        destination: Text("Success!"),
        isActive: $isActiveTwo,
        label: { EmptyView() }
      )

      Button(
        action: { self.isActiveTwo = true },
        label: { Text("Set isActiveTwo=true") }
      )
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

I expect that:

- NavigationView displays ViewOne
- ViewOne has isActiveOne == true, so the first NavigationLink destination is displayed (showing ViewTwo)
- ViewTwo has isActiveTwo == true, so the second NavigationLink destination is displayed (showing "Success!")

However, when I run this code on the iOS 14.5 simulator, the second NavigationLink is not automatically displayed (and I just see the ViewTwo Button text).

What I also find strange is that if I default isActiveTrue to false, and then press the button, it navigates correctly - something about the combination of the default "true" state + the nested navigation link seems to be causing the issue.

Any idea if this is a bug in SwiftUI? Or have I done something wrong with my setup here?

Any thoughts would be a *huge* help - I've been banging my head against the wall for a while now...

[image: Preview Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug, you can file it at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

A temporary workaround would be to put your `NavigationLink`s inside a List. That seems to work on iOS 14.5 and 15 (beta 2)

### Invisible List

If you don't want the List behaviour/look then you can put the list on the background and make it transparent (with the `opacity` modifier)

Here is an example of the invisible List workaround:

```
struct WorkaroundLink<Destination: View>: View {
    let destination: Destination
    let isActive: Binding<Bool>

    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: destination,
                isActive: isActive,
                label: { EmptyView() }
            )
        }.opacity(0.01)
    }
}

extension View {
    func workaroundLink<D: View>(to destination: D, isActive: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        background(WorkaroundLink(destination: destination, isActive: isActive))
    }
}
```

Rewriting your example with this construct becomes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView { ViewOne() }
    }
}

struct ViewOne: View {
    @State var isActiveOne = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View One")
            Button("Set isActiveOne=true") { isActiveOne = true }
        }.workaroundLink(to: ViewTwo(), isActive: $isActiveOne)
    }
}

struct ViewTwo: View {
    @State var isActiveTwo = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View Two")

            Button(
                action: { self.isActiveTwo = true },
                label: { Text("Set isActiveTwo=true") }
            )
        }.workaroundLink(to: Text("Success!"), isActive: $isActiveTwo)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Damiaan!

I've gone ahead and filed a bug through feedback-assistant [FB9321916].

Unfortunately a List doesn't seem to work for my case (unless there is some way to fully hide it?) - I was hoping to manage the routing all programatically... I'll spend some time investigating and see if there is some other workaround for my case.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes there is a (somewhat clumsy) way to (almost) fully hide the list. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ah - creative workaround! Thank you for looping back and adding an updated example - really appreciate it! :)